# Symfony3 security.exception_listener.class not working

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to manipulate the login target path in Symfony security, since my app makes some AJAX calls. I followed [this documentation article](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/target_path.html), but nothing happens (so I assumed `security.exception_listener.class` didn't "hook" properly). When I googled I found [this issue](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/15534) from 2015 on github which claims the solution in the provided documentation would be invalid in Symfony >= 3.

Now I'm just wondering - does anyone know if the linked documentation is actually out of date (which seems to be the case as it does not work for me), and how do you accomplish the same thing in Symfony 3?

Comment: You can try with Symfony 2.8 (that is currently better than 3.*, being an LTS, at least until 3.4 will be out). Just replace the constraint for "symfony/symfony" to "2.8.*" in your composer.json and run composer update

Comment: I guess it's an option, even though it certainly isn't tempting. But they can't have removed such an important feature can they?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I tried the solution shown in the comments of the issue and it works for me. Would prefer a parameter though.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for Symfony 2.7 has been updated to use a compiler pass: https://symfony.com/doc/2.7/security/target_path.html

I imagine that this change will flow through to the later versions of the documentation soon.

```php
// src/AppBundle/Security/Firewall/ExceptionListener.php
namespace AppBundle\Security\Firewall;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\ExceptionListener as BaseExceptionListener;

class ExceptionListener extends BaseExceptionListener
{
    protected function setTargetPath(Request $request)
    {
        // Do not save target path for XHR requests
        // You can add any more logic here you want
        // Note that non-GET requests are already ignored
        if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
            return;
        }

        parent::setTargetPath($request);
    }
}
```

```php
// src/AppBundle/DependencyInjection/Compiler/ExceptionListenerPass.php
namespace AppBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CompilerPassInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use AppBundle\Security\Firewall\ExceptionListener;

class ExceptionListenerPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        // Use the name of your firewall for the suffix e.g. 'secured_area'
        $definition = $container->getDefinition('security.exception_listener.secured_area');
        $definition->setClass(ExceptionListener::class);
    }
}
```

```php
// src/AppBundle/AppBundle.php
namespace AppBundle;

use AppBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler\ExceptionListenerPass;

class AppBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function build(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $container->addCompilerPass(new ExceptionListenerPass());
    }
}
```